# Unable to save data on Parse Cloud

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am saving data on parse cloud but unable to retrieve it with ParseQuery. I don't now what is going wrong? Is there any login or Signup functionality for using Parse APIs or any thing else. Please suggest any solution regarding the same.

**Save Data Code:**

```
ParseObject pObj = new ParseObject("CardTable");
                    pObj.put("name", edEmpName.getText().toString());
                    pObj.put("fromDate", btnTimeFrame1.getText().toString());
                    pObj.put("toDate", btnTimeFrame2.getText().toString());
                    pObj.saveInBackground();
```

**Get Data:**

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("CardTable");
        query.whereEqualTo("name", bundle.getString("EMP_NAME"));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " scores");

                    Toast.makeText(TimeCardWeeksActivity.this, scoreList.get(scoreList.size()-1).getString("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(TimeCardWeeksActivity.this, "failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried omitting whereEqualTo filter?

Comment: Yes I tried, but result remains same, I was not able to get My saved data. Even its perfectly working with iOS.

Comment: Please add callback in save and see the result of callback that it is saved successfully or not.

Comment: Can you suggest me DroidDev, How to add callback on save?

Comment: you can add a callback by doing: `pObj.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() { @Override public void done(ParseException e) { if (e != null) e.printStackTrace(); } });` instead of just `pObj.saveInBackground();`